# Difference between these two new relic commands

Tags: php, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I see these two commands in newrelic installation guide.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/installation/php-agent-installation-ubuntu-debian

```
sudo apt-get install newrelic-php5
```

and

```
sudo newrelic-install install
```

When i run the first command, i get an interface to input license key and application name. Let's say i have given name `Php Application Dev` here.

When i run the second command i am only asked for license key in a command line interface and name is automatically set to `Php Application`.

When i log in to newrelic interface from browser i see two application `Php Application Dev` and `Php Application`. But i see data only coming to `Php Application`. What is the reason behind that?